# Camunda Authorization of cockpit-application not working

Tags: authorization, camunda

I authorized the group of a user to the **cockpit**-application. I gave the group full access to the **Process Definition** and **Process Instance** authorizations. (so pretty much as described in the [documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/webapps/admin/authorization-management/#application-specific-permissions))

When I try to log the user in, I see the Welcome screen and in the application overview the option to navigate to the cockpit-application.

[image]

However, when I click this, I get the Login screen again.

[image]

For a fraction of a second I see the cockpit application, but then it immidiatly redirects to the login page. When I try to log in again, it keeps redirecting me to this login screen.

I configured another group to use the Tasklist application and that is working as expected.

I tried to give the authorization on user-level instead of group-level but the same problems occurs.

*(n.b.: I am using the Spring-Camunda-Starter for this application.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I accidentally removed one of the authorizations the system automatically creates when the user is created. I think I might have removed this, as I thought it was not necessary.

It is in the **User Authorizations**, every user has an authorization from it's own  user to that user. When I added this, it fixed the problem.

I found the solution when another user logged in and had no problems. And the found this to be the only difference between the two accounts.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future!